# Trasncribe ogg file using Speech SDK from Microsoft Azure

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I've been trying to trasncript an (.ogg) file using the SpeechSDK of cognitive services from Azure. But I can not make it work. Below is my code:

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import time

speech_key, service_region = "my-subscription", "eastus"
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
speech_config.speech_recognition_language="es-ES"
# audio_filename = "AudioTest.wav"
audio_filename = "AudioFile.ogg"

def speech_recognize_continuous_from_file():
    """performs continuous speech recognition with input from an audio file"""
    # <SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=audio_filename)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that signals to stop continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    # speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
    # speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    # speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    # speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))

    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    # Start continuous speech recognition
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)

    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    # </SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    speech_recognize_continuous_from_file()
```

The problem is when I try it with a (.wav) file it works perfectly but when I try it with the .ogg file I got the following error record

```
(796): 24ms SPX_THROW_HR_IF: (0x00a) = 0xa
(41): 85ms SPX_RETURN_ON_FAIL: hr = 0x47a4dbe0
SPX_RETURN_ON_FAIL: hr = recognizer_start_continuous_recognition_async_wait_for(m_hasyncStartContinuous, 0xffffffffui32) = 0x47a4dbe0
SPX_THROW_ON_FAIL: hr = 0x47a4dbe0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jramirezs\Documents\VisualStudioCode\Testing5.py", line 44, in <module>
    speech_recognize_continuous_from_file()    
  File "c:\Users\jramirezs\Documents\VisualStudioCode\Testing5.py", line 36, in speech_recognize_continuous_from_file
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
  File "C:\Python64bit\lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\speech\speech.py", line 404, in start_continuous_recognition
    return self._impl.start_continuous_recognition()
  File "C:\Python64bit\lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\speech\speech_py_impl.py", line 3679, in start_continuous_recognition
    return _speech_py_impl.SpeechRecognizer_start_continuous_recognition(self)
RuntimeError: Exception with an error code: 0xa (SPXERR_INVALID_HEADER)
[CALL STACK BEGIN]

    > CreateModuleObject

    - CreateModuleObject

    - CreateModuleObject

    - CreateModuleObject

    - CreateModuleObject

    - 00007FFFF2B50BAF (SymFromAddr() error: Se ha intentado tener acceso a una direcci�n no v�lida.)

    - CreateModuleObject

    - CreateModuleObject

    - CreateModuleObject

    - CreateModuleObject

    - o_exp

    - BaseThreadInitThunk

    - RtlUserThreadStart



[CALL STACK END]
```

Any help will be appreciate, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@juanferrs.

Currently in SpeechSDK we do not support compressed input for python language. We have it only for C#, Java, C++ and ObjectiveC.

It is in the plan to support compressed input for python language. Please subscribe to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/releasenotes for the next release.